# Google Analytics Custom Dimension Not Tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to use Google Analytic's custom dimensions to do some a/b testing, but nothing shows up in the reports. Here's what I did:

Created a custom dimension:
Index: 1
Scope: Session
Active: checked

Then I modified my GA code to look like this:

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-9541894-2', 'auto');

  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'a' );

  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

When I turn on Analytics inspector, I see that it is sending my custom dimension value. But I never see anything in the reporting. I even waited a day to see if it took time to process. Any idea what's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Where are you looking ? Custom Dimensions do not show up in the standard reports by default. You have to select them as secondary dimension or create a custom report. And no do not confuse them with "custom variables", that menu item will only show values if you use "classic" analytics.

Comment: DId you ever find the solution to this problem ? Got the same one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use secondary dimension

[image]

You can look that web site. 
https://davidsimpson.me/2014/04/20/tutorial-send-user-ids-google-analytics/